# Cannot change password for user

Tags: permissions, kali-linux

I am running Kali Linux 2020.2 on a VirtualBox VM; I am trying to change my password from the default, using the command:

```
sudo passwd ollie
```

For user `ollie` (me).  It prompts me for the new password, and then to retype it.  Both times I entered the correct password; it says:

```
passwd: password successfully changed!
```

But then later, when doing an update with the `sudo` command, it prompts me for the password.  I try the new one: incorrect, it says.  Then I typed the default one, and it continues!  I have tried quite a few things from online, but they all result in this.  How can I *permanently* change my password without it resetting every reboot (it does)?  Are there certain files I should edit?

Comment: Yes, it means a reboot.  I shut it down and came back an hour later, but also tested a change of passwords with a reboot.  Same result.

Comment: Does the new password work in other contexts (such as `su ollie`)?)

Comment: Is your `sudoers` perhaps configured to use `rootpw`?

Comment: I am not famiiar with Kali, but Ubuntu allows the user to change their password through `System Settings / Users` while the user is logged in.  Does Kali not have that?  Also, can't you just type `passwd` in a terminal window while logged in as ollie and change your password without using `sudo`?  Sorry for my ignorance,

Comment: @steeldriver, if you mean the `/etc/sudoers` file with the `Defaults rootpw` line, then no.

Comment: @StephenDaddona, I have tried just `passwd`, which updates the password then falls back to default WITHOUT a reboot.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas.  I am surprised that this has gone 9 days without anyone knowing what to do about it.

Comment: kali is full with weired behaviors ,not sure but try to go root first `sudo -i` then change it `passwd ollie`  (that's what i did long time ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue long time ago with Kali, and I used to successfully change a user password from root instead of using sudo:

```
$ sudo -i
# passwd ollie
```

Comment: Jonah, thank you again, and upvoted :)